# Linq to join tables on XElement.Name = XAttribute("n")

Tags: c#, xml, linq, join

This is driving me bat-guano crazy!
Client data file:

```
<rows>
    <row>
        <CustomerID>ABC123</CustomerID>
        <PrdcrCd>10</PrdcrCd>
        <StrAdr>123 Main St., NW</StrAdr>
        <City>Anytown</City>
        etc.
    </row>
<rows>
```

Map file for transforming client data into acceptable input:

```
<SourceEntries>
    <map>
        <Field n='CustomerID' m='201' />
        <Field n='StrAdr' m='315' />
        <Field n='City' m='316' />
        <Field n='PrdrCd' m='442' />
        etc.
    </map>
</SourceEntries>
```

Finally, the template for acceptable input:

```
<template>
    <Field n='ClientId' id='201' />
    <Field n='Street Address' id='315' />
    <Field n='City' id='316' />
    <Field n='ProducerCode' id='442' />
    etc.
</template>
```

So, from the client file XElement name, match the Source Entries attribute value 'n', and get the Source Entires map reference m. Then, use m to match a template element attribute i, retrieve the template name attribute 'n' and create a new XElement tree using that name.

Since I'm a noob at Linq, and not particularly adept at XML, I thought I'd start out slowly. Like this:

```
var results = from t1 in clientXm.Elements("row").Descendants()
      join t2 in sourceEntries.Elements("Field") on t1.Name equals t2.Attributes("n") into xRef
      select new
          {
              (string)xRef.Attributes("n"),
              (string)xRef.Attributes("m")
          };
```

First error, in the join clause at "on t1.Name.LocalName equals" is that Argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'TKey'. Then, in the select clause, for the two items I'm interested in, I get "Anonymous type projection initializer should be simple name or member access expression." Oh, and of course, the XML file structures are specification requirements, so I can't change any of them.

At this point, I'm so freaking confused I don't know whether the world is upside-down, or I'm standing on my head. Can I please buy a clue... or at least a vowel? Any and all help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Using LinqPad, I tried this statement:

```
XElement _clientXml = XElement.Load(@"client.xml");
XElement _sourceEntries = XElement.Load(@"Client_Map.xml");

foreach (XElement clientData in _clientXml.Descendants("row").Descendants()){
    IEnumerable<XElement> mapRefs =
        from mapData in _sourceEntries.Descendants("Field")
        where clientData.Name.LocalName == (string) mapData.Attribute("n")
        select mapData;
    foreach (XElement item in mapRefs){
        Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("m"));
    }   
}
```

In LinqPad, this produced a list of "m" values -- just what I'm trying to get at this baby step. BUT the exact same code in VS gives me nothing. When I debug, mapRefs is an empty set when I get to the second foreach.

Does this make any sense at all?

Thanks
Randy

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize how much my frustration level was showing through... Please forgive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your inputs aren't aligned quite right. Here's a good starting place:

```
var rowText = 
@"<rows>
    <row>
        <CustomerID>ABC123</CustomerID>
        <PrdrCd>10</PrdrCd>
        <StrAdr>123 Main St., NW</StrAdr>
        <City>Anytown</City>
        etc.
    </row>
</rows>";
var sourceEntriesText =
@"<SourceEntries>
    <map>
        <Field n='CustomerID' m='201' />
        <Field n='StrAdr' m='315' />
        <Field n='City' m='316' />
        <Field n='PrdrCd' m='442' />
        etc.
    </map>
</SourceEntries>";
var templateText =
@"<template>
    <Field n='ClientId' id='201' />
    <Field n='Street Address' id='315' />
    <Field n='City' id='316' />
    <Field n='ProducerCode' id='442' />
    etc.
</template>";
var clientXm = XDocument.Parse(rowText);
var sourceEntries = XDocument.Parse(sourceEntriesText);
var results = from r in clientXm.Descendants("row")
            from t1 in r.Elements()
            let xRef = sourceEntries.Descendants("Field").FirstOrDefault(
                        t2 => t1.Name == t2.Attribute("n").Value)
            select new
                {
                    t1,
                    xRef
                };
```

A little more work yields something probably closer to what you're looking for:

```
var results = from r in clientXm.Descendants("row")
            from t1 in r.Elements()
            join t2 in sourceEntries.Descendants("Field")
            on t1.Name equals t2.Attribute("n").Value
            join t3 in template.Descendants("Field")
            on t2.Attribute("m").Value equals t3.Attribute("id").Value
            select new
                {
                    Name = t3.Attribute("n").Value,
                    Value = t1.Value,
                };
```

Comment: This looks like it should work; particularly the second example. Unfortunately, I'm not getting any results. Gonna have to start with little baby steps and see how far I get. Thank you, though, for the help.

Comment: @EoRaptor013: I used the given code in LINQPad, and it produced results. You might want to check your XML inputs. Your producer code mapping, for example, doesn't match. There were a few other issues, too.

Comment: No joy. Where this seems to blow up is that I can't get a match between the client data XElement.XName.LocalName and the map data (string) XElement.XAttribute("n") name. Even though the two strings actually do match -- from looking at them in the source files, the join can't pick it up. Is there a way to debug these statements so I can see what attribute n is returning? 

Thanks.

Comment: Downloaded LinqPad (as a possible debugger). a simple query returned data. That selfsame query in VS returns no results. Is there any way to trace through the execution of the statements in VS?

Comment: @EoRaptor013: Not really. That's one of the weaker points of LINQ. However, you should get the same results from LINQPad as you get in Visual Studio. I strongly suspect that either your code or your XML is different. Try pasting everything from LINQPad directly into Visual Studio and see if you get results then.

Comment: You were right. The client template contains everything but the actual client data. To make it easier for me to use, I parsed it into separate XML trees for the template, the map, and the source fields. I buggered that up earlier in the code and that's why I didn't get any matches. Oh well. 

Thank you for your help straightening me out.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's easy to fix the compiler errors:

```
var results = from t1 in clientXm.Elements("row").Descendants()
              join t2 in sourceEntries.Elements("Field")
              on t1.Name.LocalName equals (string) t2.Attribute("n") into xRef
              select new
              {
                  N = (string)xRef.Attributes("n"),
                  M = (string)xRef.Attributes("m")
              };
```

However, I'm not sure how you're intending the cast from `IEnumerable<XAttribute>` to `string` to work in the projection...

I suspect you *don't* want a group join (which is what you get with join...into. But I don't understand how your data sample works, so it's hard to give you the correct code. Where should `ClientId` come from, for example? You've only got it in your sample *output*... assuming that *is* your sample output, of course.

Basically, if you could simplify your sample data into two inputs and an output, and explain how the output is derived, that would make life easier... at the moment it's not clear.

Comment: CustomerID in client file matches to SourceEntries attribute n='CustomerID'. SourceEntries attribute m='201' then points to template attribute id='201'. Template attribute n='ClientId' gives me the new element name.

Comment: So far, all I'm trying to do here is simply retrieve the appropriate 'n' and 'm' attributes from the Source Entries file. The next step would be to join the Template file on sourceEntries.m = template.id. I would then create a new XML tree using the template attribute n value as the element name. If there's a better way to do this, given the constraints in the three files, I would be terribly grateful to hear it.